# I want to return z as int but I can't return it

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to return `z` as an `int` but am unable to do so. The code that I am using to achieve this is shown here below.

```
public static int pagenumber(String DBmatter, String ClassYear) throws SQLException {

        Statement stmt;
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from page_number where 'matter_name' = '" + DBmatter + ClassYear + "';");
        while (rs.next()) {
            String y = rs.getString(3);
            int z = Integer.parseInt(y);
        }
        return z ;

    }
```

Comment: You don't have an error output, but I'm going to take a shot in the dark and guess that `stmt.executeQuery(...)` is not a static method and therefore cannot be run from a static context.

Comment: Because z was a variable inside "while" you have to declare variable `z` before you give the value to `z`.

Comment: What do you want to return if the query doesn't return any rows? What do you want to return if the query returns multiple rows?

Comment: Since the column order of a table doesn't have to remain fixed, how do you know which column `getString(3)` is retrieving? I highly recommend you change the query to list the desired column name, and then use `getString(1)` or `getString("columnname")`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Statement stmt;
stmt = con.createStatement();
int z = 0;
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from page_number where 'matter_name' = '" + DBmatter + ClassYear + "';");
while (rs.next()) {
    String y = rs.getString(3);
    z = Integer.parseInt(y);
}
return z ;
```

There is nothing wrong with your code, you just need to declare `z` outside of `while`.

Comment: even with this its return the value of the (z) out while

Comment: @MagdyEl-Nagar: Yes, but it is also _declared_ outside of the loop (see line 3, `int z;`).  Variables are not available outside of the scope they are declared, and in _your_ version of the code, `z` is declared within the `while` loop's scope.  Once you have exited the `while` loop, `z` is no longer defined.

Comment: The explanation from @BeUndead is clear, it's just that simple.

Comment: ***Compilation error:*** `z` is not definitely assigned in `return z`

Answer (score 0):

thx i have resolve it with this code

```
    String y = "";
    Statement stmt;
    stmt = con.createStatement(); ///SELECT number FROM page_number where matter_name='loghty1B';
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select number from page_number where matter_name='" + DBmatter + ClassYear + "';");

    while (rs.next()) {
        y = rs.getString("number");
        System.out.println("this from Go DB @ While " + y);
        return y;
    }
    return y;

}
```